# Radar antenna for distance measurement

Tags: rf, antenna, radar

I am working on a project where we have decided to use radar to measure the distance of an object from the device.

I have been using Infineon's BGT24MTR11 (24GHz) evaluation board, (Sense2go), which comes with an integrated patch antenna already onboard.

[image]

It will detect movement approximately 5m from the board.

However, we need to accurately measure the distance of objects approximately **100m** from the transmitter and have a required detection radius of 10°.

There are issues around [24GHz](http://www.etsi.org/technologies-clusters/technologies/intelligent-transport/automotive-radar), (temporary band, astronomy stations, etc.), so we may actually move to 77GHz or 79GHz but for the moment I am sticking with 24GHz.

**edit** *As kindly pointed out by Brian Drummond the sense2go module will not measure 100m, so the 24GHz is not an option and sense2go is off the list .*

[image]

The regulatory body ETSI, lists only three automotive radar frequencies, 24, 77 & 79GHz, http://www.etsi.org/technologies-clusters/technologies/intelligent-transport/automotive-radar. 77GHz seems to be the most popular.

The next evaluation board on our list comes from [Altera](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01183-automotive-radar-socfpga.pdf)  This has a centre frequency around 77GHz.  I tried contacting the supplier of the demo antenna but they did not get back and the feedback I have been getting is that unless you are tier 1 or a major OEM they won't talk to you.

I have been looking in vain for commercially available antennas that will work at these frequencies.

Something like Delphi's [system](http://delphi.com/docs/default-source/product-profile-pdfs/delphi-integrated-radar-and-camera-system-racam.pdf) would be ideal.

I am considering designing the antenna using [cst](https://www.cst.com/Products/CSTDS), however I have limited experience in antenna design and there are no antenna design experts on the team.

Can anyone make a recommendation for a best course of action (77GHz)?

Comment: Given the fourth power "radar law" you need to increase (transmit power * sensitivity) by (100/5) ** 4, or 160000 times. I don't think changing the antenna will do it.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  There is a disconnect somewhere as the FAE was saying the chip could be capable of 100m object measurement with a 30/ 40cm accuracy.  Maybe we need a better receiver/ DSP?  I am looking at an altera module in the new year which definitely meets the spec, unfortunately it uses a proprietary antenna which cannot be purchased. I guess the question remains, patch, horn, active.  What would be the best solution?

Comment: At least if you do use a high gain antenna you get its benefit twice - on both transmit and receive, but it still looks like a challenge. I expect the FAE is in a better position to explain how to get the range he claims than we are.

Comment: Try putting the evaluation board at the focus of a small (1-2 foot) parabolic dish.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Definitely a challenge but one that has been conquered by delphi.  The FAE suggested contacting a few companies such as Flann Microwave, which I did but again no feedback as yet. Any suggestion on how to proceed with 77GHz, design or buy?

Comment: If there is no antenna design expertise on your team, I would recommend buying.  Antenna design is not a trivial task for the uninitiated

Comment: Especially at 77 GHz

Comment: @johnnymopo Would love to throw money at it but unfortunately don't have the budget.

Comment: Never worked with such high frequencies. I did work at a company which designed FMCW radar and multi-mode radar. I think you will want a parabolic reflector. At the focus, you would place a horn type 77 GHz antenna (the aperture would be aimed backwards into the center of the reflector). Hopefully your budget will allow you to purchase a 77 GHz horn.

Comment: Is there a bandwidth requirement? Why  >= 24 GHz?

Comment: @johnnymopo It's automotive radar, in Europe it's governed by ETSI http://www.etsi.org/technologies-clusters/technologies/intelligent-transport/automotive-radar  Also,  of interest http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/302200_302299/30226401/01.01.01_30/en_30226401v010101v.pdf Certain bands are restricted etc. also it's probably related to the electromagnetic absorption profile.

Comment: Ah, no I get why 24 & 77 exist, I assumed you were just using the equipment for something else.  What antenna are referring to in the altera link?  I did not actually see a reference to a specific antenna

Comment: @johnnymopo I had to talk to the FAE to get details.  They used a delphi antenna as part of the evaluation system

Comment: To design the antenna I need to know how will it be connected with the radar module. I couldn't find any specification of the ALTERA module. To calculate the necessary antenna gain it is necessary. Do you have any restriction in the dimension? Patch, horn or parabolic reflector is possible. You have to find the right company to make it.

Answer (score 3):

At 77GHz the tolerances for "antenna" design are so small, that it would take a very experienced antenna designer to design such an antenna. Which in reality is a wave guide, not an antenna in the traditional term.

Stick with commercially available antenna systems: or stick the whole board in the focal position of a parabolic dish as suggested in the comments.

Comment: phase array antennas seem to be the norm at this frequency: http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/49859/media/fig1.png  In my investigation to date, parabolics have not been used.

Answer (score 1):

Older post, but thought I'd offer an up to date response. I recommend checking out the Texas Instruments IWR and AWR FMCW 77GHz Radar SoC.

http://www.ti.com/sensing-products/mmwave/overview.html

The Boosterpack style EVM kits include all layout files, schematics and bill of materials. Demo software also included which provides simple range, velocity and angle of arrival estimation. These are examples of working 76-81GHz antenna, as well as GCPW transmission line, and BGA to transmission-line to get you started.

http://www.ti.com/tool/iwr1443boost

http://www.ti.com/tool/iwr1642boost